# cpp char to float not working

Tags: c++, floating-point, char

I am trying to convert `char* argv[]` values into float as following:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    float num1;
    num1 = atof(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I even tried `num1 = (float) (argv[1])`. But not working. Please help.
But it is not working. Giving error as follows

```
parampass.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
parampass.cpp:8:11: error: redeclaration of 'float num1'
     float num1 = atof(argv[1]);
           ^
parampass.cpp:7:11: error: 'float num1' previously declared here
     float num1;
           ^
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Runtime or compile time error?

Comment: What: `cout << argv[1] << endl;` prints ?

Comment: @AdamF yup it works!!

Comment: @Santhucool you have edited the code and I think the issue is no longer observed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erase the float in `float num1 = atof(argv[1])`;
You already declared the variable above. You can't declare the same variable twice. This doesn't exist in the code you pasted in the question which is correct. Which I guess means you managed to solve it yourself.